# I'm playing around with storing user inputted data via JavaScript, need assistance

Tags: javascript, storage

I'm trying to setup a website that stores how many hours a user exercised into an array, saves the array to the users computer, then logs the array to the console the next time the page is loaded. Here is what I have so far, but it's not working. Any suggestions?

```
// Script

init();

function init() {

    if (localStorage.getItem('exerciseData') !== null && localStorage.getItem('exerciseData') !== undefined) {
        exerciseData = localStorage.getItem('exerciseData');
        console.log(exerciseData);
    } else {
        console.log('blank exercise data array');
        exerciseData = [];
    }
}


let x = document.createElement("INPUT");
x.setAttribute("type", "text");
x.setAttribute("value", "How long did you exercise today?");
x.size = "40";
document.body.appendChild(x);
document.write('     ');
let btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
btn.innerHTML = "Submit";   
document.body.appendChild(btn);

var exerciseData = [];
console.log('test');

btn.onclick = function () {
    var date = new Date();
    let day = date.getDate();
    let month = date.getMonth();
    let year = date.getFullYear();
    exerciseData.push(`${day}/${month + 1}/${year} : ${x.value}`);
    //exerciseData.push(day + '/' + (month + 1) + '/' + year + ':' + x.value);
    localStorage.setItem("exerciseData", exerciseData); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks like it'll work if you move your `exerciseData` definition to the top, before calling `init()`.

Right now, it's overridden with an empty `[]` as you're defining it after running `init()`.

Another issue is `document.createElement()` statements should use lowercase element names instead of `INPUT` or `BUTTON`.

Finally, you cannot store an array in `localStorage`, but you are able to store strings. So, storing/getting data should use strings, not arrays:

```
localStorage.setItem("exerciseData", JSON.stringify(exerciseData));

//...
exerciseData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("exerciseData"));
```

Comment: When I moved exerciseData to the top:

script.js:37 Uncaught TypeError: exerciseData.push is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.btn.onclick (script.js:37)

Comment: it's probably because you already have `exerciseData` in your localStorage that is not an array. in this case, remove your localStorage content and try again.

Comment: actually, you cannot store arrays in local storage. please see my updated answer.

Comment: Now I'm getting this error when trying to add new exercise data elements to the array:

script.js:38 Uncaught TypeError: exerciseData.push is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.btn.onclick (script.js:38)

Comment: see the last line of my answer. you need to parse your data when getting it from localStorage.

Comment: Is there a way to store arrays?

Comment: as I put in my answer, it's only possible to store strings. that's why you stringify it before saving it, and parse it after fetching it.

Comment: When I add exerciseData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("exerciseData")), this happens:

VM5992:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at init (script.js:12)
    at script.js:7

Comment: you're welcome. if it worked for you, can you accept the answer?

Comment: Sure thing. Is there a way I can communicate with you aside from stackoverflow?

Comment: I suppose emailing would be superior to texting. I guess emailing. I'd love to ask you questions so I can learn. And I'm sure it would feel good for you to demonstrate your knowledge and expertise by answering those questions. So I think email is best.

Comment: sure, what's your email?

Comment: rostaryms@gmail.com. Please shoot me an email! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I hope that can help.

```
let x = document.createElement("input");
x.setAttribute("type", "text");
x.setAttribute("value", "How long did you exercise today?");
x.size = "40";
document.body.appendChild(x);
document.write('     ');
let btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
btn.innerHTML = "Submit";   
document.body.appendChild(btn);


function time() {
    const date = new Date();
    let day = date.getDate();
    let month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    let year = date.getFullYear();
    return [day, month, year];
}

function isLocalStorageSet() {
    return localStorage.getItem('exerciseData') ? true : false;
}

function getLocalStorage() {
    return localStorage.getItem('exerciseData');
}

function setLocalStorage() {
    if (validate()) {
        [day, month, year] = time();
        last = x.value;
        localStorage.setItem('exerciseData', `${day}/${month}/${year} : ${x.value} Hour`);
        msg(getLocalStorage())
        return;
    } 
    msg('the value has to be Number');
}

function validate() {
    return !isNaN(x.value);
}

function msg($error) {
    console.log($error);
}

if (isLocalStorageSet()) {
    msg(getLocalStorage());
}

btn.onclick = setLocalStorage;
```